# PERL: Read file into Array in Loop

Tags: arrays, perl, while-loop

I see there are many questions very similar to this but I am unable to find the answer and trying to piece it together based on these answers isn't working either.

GOAL: Using Perl, read a file (`./perlscript.pl input.txt`) input.txt will have several lines
example:

```
hosangit.com,5
djzah.com,3
251.26.192.in-addr.arpa,3
26.192.in-addr.arpa,5
```

Perl script needs to process line by line in a while loop so it addresses each line in the input.txt file

Read line and utilize separator of , and place into two variables DOMAIN and NS (NS stands for name servers in this case)

Run IF statement
`IF $DOMAIN` ends with .in-addr.arpa then utilize separator of . and place into an array else run a command)... after placed into an array find position of arpa so to right `$DOMAIN` with either (in this example) 192.26.251.0/24 or 192.26.0.0/16
Need to perform an action if line in input.txt ends with in-addr.arpa otherwise continue.

I know this is alot but it would really help me get going with the rest of the script if I could see how to get started.

Comment: Perl can be learned
http://www.perl.com/pub/2000/10/begperl1.html

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, the following will split input on ",":

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

while (<>) {
   my ($domain, $ns)=split(/,/);

}
```